# Firefox does not send request for some (cached?) pages?

Tags: firefox, caching

We are working on a Java EE project for some time now and recently we have experienced a problem where suddenly on some clients the pages wouldn't load.

Using firebug we saw that some Javascript resources didn't load (the attached pic) and then by testing via Wireshark we found out that Firefox doesn't send a request for these resources. 
The interesting part is that after deleting the local Firefox cache on a client that page loads as normal, therefore it seems there is a problem with resources that are cached locally.

As we have never experienced this until recently could it be due to a bug in newer versions of Firefox (28+) as we have never experienced this on something like Chrome? Any help would be much appreciated

[image: pic of firefox not being able to load resources]